# Password Strength

Tags: password

I don't understand why on my Ubuntu install there is such a small password character restriction. I think it's about 13 characters. Is there a way to modify Ubuntu so that I can have much longer passwords?

Comment: No I mean modify the OS so I can have say 20 characters. I will never leave Ubuntu I love it now!

Comment: I am not sure if this works for Ubuntu, but according to [this source](http://linuxpoison.blogspot.de/2010/10/how-to-set-password-length-in-ubuntu.html), you should edit your `/etc/pam.d/common-password` file and modify the line containing `pam_unix.so` by adding the words `max=20` between `obscure` and `sha512` (or similar). Please report if it worked and I will convert this to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Password complexity in Ubuntu is controlled by PAM.

`man pam_unix`

```
   pam_unix - Module for traditional password authentication

   This is the standard Unix authentication module. It uses standard calls
   from the system's libraries to retrieve and set account information as
   well as authentication. Usually this is obtained from the /etc/passwd
   and the /etc/shadow file as well if shadow is enabled.
```

Open the file that controls password complexity:

```
sudo gedit /etc/pam.d/common-password
```

There is a line:

```
password [success=1 default=ignore] pam_unix.so obscure sha512
```

Which defines the basic rules for password complexity. You can add a minimum length override by changing it to:

```
password [success=1 default=ignore] pam_unix.so obscure sha512 minlen=20
```

Replace `20` with min numb of characters  you want to use for your password save and exit.

Read [this](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/User-Authentication-HOWTO/x115.html) and [this](http://wpollock.com/AUnix2/PAM-Help.htm) to learn more about PAM.

Comment: Thanks. Are you sure it is the minimum value you have to change? I wanted to just increase the maximum amount of characters allowed to be greater than the defaults.

Comment: then change minlen and write maxlen

Comment: @johnsmith you are welcome